# When do strings formatted with NSDateFormatterFullStyle include an era string

Tags: iphone, ios, foundation

Apple's NSDateFormatter Class Reference lists, as an example string for NSDateFormatterFullStyle:

> Specifies a full style with complete details, such as “Tuesday, April
>   12, 1952 AD” or “3:30:42pm PST”

In practice, I'm getting strings along the lines of:

> Tuesday, April 12, 1952

by using code like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This is the behavior I see in the iOS 5.0 and 4.3 simulators.

Does -[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:] only append the "AD" string for certain dates? If so, when can I expect it to happen?

There doesn't seem to be anything in the system's region format setting that would affect this.

It also doesn't seem to depend on -[NSDateFormatter eraSymbols] or -[NSDateFormatter longEraSymbols]. In my tests, both are set by default and changing them doesn't change the result of -[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:].

The actual result that I want is the string that is being generated (without the "AD"), I just want to be sure that I'm doing things correctly.

Maybe this is just a documentation error. If so, I will file a bug report, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything before doing so.